# phpBB 3.0.9 LDAP Authentication works, but doesn't create user account in LDAP

Tags: php, ldap, phpbb, phpbb3

I'm using phpBB 3.0.9 with LDAP authentication setup. Currently, I need to manually create phpbb user account (uid) in LDAP, and the user login/logout function work. But, when I register a new phpBB user account, phpBB doesn't create the user account in LDAP at the same time. So I need to manually create the same username's account at LDAP side, then the user account can login phpBB system. (I'm using openldap on an ubuntu server)

My question is, does phpBB 3.0.9 fully support LDAP? (create/read/update/delete user account at LDAP) or phpBB 3.0.9 only supports reading LDAP information only?

or should I install another extra third-party plug-in for accessing LDAP in phpBB system?

Thanks!

Comment: $ find ./ | xargs grep "ldap"
tried to search all possible source code PHP files which includes "ldap" keyword. but it only shows ./includes/auth/auth_ldap.php is the only file mentions about "ldap".

Comment: There's no create ldap user record related function in ./includes/auth/auth_ldap.php and ./includes/functions_user.php (user_add, line 152)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LDAP support in PHPBB 3.x is currently only one way, so it does not create users in LDAP when a user registers, so you will have to maintain that manually. Feel free to submit a Mod creation request in this forum and one of the PHPBB Mod creators may create one for you:

http://www.phpbb.com/community/viewforum.php?f=72

I am also not aware of any existing plugins or Mods that does this for you.

Pete